Where should I put DTO conversions in our cargo workspace?
I have a workspace with many microservices and many times I want to perform conversions between the DTOs of different services (e.g. convert the response of one service into a request for another). I'm having a hard time deciding where to put these conversions due to cargo rejecting cyclic dependencies. Some solutions I've thought of:

Decide on a convention such that conversions from crate A to crate B (A->B) belong in crate A (always the 'from' side). This means crate A depends on crate B but this precludes crate B from depending on A if it ever calls A directly (which actually happens in our codebase)
Create a separate convert crate where we store conversions, gated by both features for both involved crates. This means convert depends on both A and B so neither can use these conversions directly or otherwise that would be a cylic dependency!

I'll take any ideas to solve this cleanly

Would it be possible to create a separate protocol crate that contains the DTO's for all microservices? The conversions could live there too, or in a convert crate that depends on protocol.

To me it looks like the only choice right now but it'd have a pretty big impact on our codebase since it kind of goes against one of our major decisions for architecture

Also consider changing all your microservices to be separate binaries in one crate instead of separate crates in a workspace. You can still try to organize things, such as by using submodule directories within that one crate.

That looks kinda scary but would solve some other problems for us... don't you think there might be big tradeoffs here? Maybe compilation time would increase?

On a second thought, I don't think this is possible for us since we use sqlx's compile-time queries quite heavily, and it's not possible to configure several databases for a single crate (yet)

You're right, this issue would need to be resolved. I'm cautiously optimistic that there wouldn't be any other big tradeoffs.
